# Git Pull/Fetch Automation

Tags: linux, git, github, automation

I'm wanting to automate a local server to pull github repositories and then add copyrights to the code files, if they aren't already there, then commit and push them back.  I have the copyright executable running on the linux centOS server, but I can't get a way to tell my program to run or not.  Webhooks don't work since its a local server, not web-facing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that you could write a script to do this. The easiest would be to use a shell script or a python script.

The script could do the following.

```
Open every directory
   for each directory
       for each file in the directory
            if not contains copyright
                add copyright to top of file

git commit -m "add copyright"
git push
```